# How can I have specific information passed along each time a view is rendered in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm building a web site in Django, and I want to have some basic information added to the dictionary that is passed to the template renderer. For now, I'm just wanting a list of the static pages in my site so that I can put links in the header, but would like to be able to expand that information later.

Answer (score 4):

### Context Processors

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

It's just a function that takes 1 argument, request, and returns a dictionary. [Specify active processors in your settings file.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext)

```
def MyProcessor(request):
     return {'im_available_in_every_template': 'that uses RequestContext'}
```

Oh, note that this only works on views that use [`RequestContext`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext)  --
I just haven't not used `RequestContext` in 3 years I keep forgetting to mention it.

Comment: Is there any reason not to just use RequestContext everywhere?

Comment: Sure, there's no need for it in many of my AJAX calls that don't even use a template. Generally, I need access to my logged in user, so I always use it. Is there any reason not to? Only if you don't need what it provides... It might not seem like much of an answer, but that's the bottom line. Sure I'd save a few database hits for the session and user, but I need those.